# Mashing vessel inside oven to avoid heat loss

Tags: mashing, small-batch

I just saw a YouTube video where since guy puts the mashing tun - a pot in this case - in the oven to help with heat loss. 
I believe he didn't heat it, but world heating the oven to around mash temperature would help? Is this a common technique for small batch brewing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not, unless you set up a custom temp control for the oven. Most ovens start at 200°F which is much higher than any mash temp.

Putting in a warm oven with it off could be done easily with a manual thermometer. Just turn it off when it gets to mash temp and it should hold the heat nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea.  My oven starts out at 170 F.  You can get it up to 170, turn it off for a while, open and close the door, and it'll be about the right temp.

I used to use my oven somewhat when I used a pot for a mash tun, but I use plastic now.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a cooler mash tun with very little $ and only lose a degree or 2 per hour temp. The oven seems a bit unorthodox and tedious.